# Chromedriver in Java not executable

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

So i'm trying to to learn Selenium and encountered a problem.
Can't run chromedriver.

**Error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver is not executable: /Users/Roberto/Documents/EclipseProjects/MansPirmaisSelenium/lib/chromedriver
```

**Code:**

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"//lib//chromedriver");
WebDriver chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver();
chromeDriver.get("http://www.google.lv");
```

I have my chromedriver in the right path i guess, here is the image.
[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I assume you just downloaded the chromedriver application, in which case you simply have to [mark it as executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) in Unix:

```
chmod +x chromedriver
```

If you can run the application yourself from the terminal, then WebDriver should be able to as well.

By the way, I wouldn't include `chromedriver` inside your project:

- You'll want to reuse it on other projects
- According to the [documentation](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started):

> include the ChromeDriver location in your PATH environment variable

Answer (score 3):

File permissions for Unix based files can be checked and set via java like:

Check if the file permission allow :

```
file.canExecute(); – return true, file is executable; false is not.
file.canWrite(); – return true, file is writable; false is not.
file.canRead(); – return true, file is readable; false is not.
```

Set the file permission :

```
file.setExecutable(boolean); – true, allow execute operations; false to disallow it.
file.setReadable(boolean); – true, allow read operations; false to disallow it.
file.setWritable(boolean); – true, allow write operations; false to disallow it.
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to selenium-java and faced the same problem and solved by providing executable access as below in eclipse:

1. Right click on chromedriver and click properties
2. Under Resource Tab check owner > execute

Answer (score -1):

The problem is exactly in permissions to the chromedriver in the target directory. To solve the problem author mentioned above change your chromedrive initialization to the following:

```
System.setProperty(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/test/resources/chromedriver");
```

of course use your own appropriate directory to the file.